# How to set 'Referer' HTTP header using Apache HttpComponents HttpClient

Tags: java, php, curl

I wrote php curl to request some data from my API server, and now I want to develop a JSP to request the data from the same API server.

The problem comes when my API server need http referer to check if the request come from a valid url.

My original PHP is:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example.com/1');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

... then my api server get the referer url with

```
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

How do I use Apache HttpComponents HttpClient to set the `Referer` header?

Comment: Are you asking 'how can I set the HTTP `Referer` header using a Java HTTP library?'

Comment: that is what i want .. i just don't know how to describe it .. and can send it to my api server

Comment: Which Java HTTP client library are use using?

Comment: i use Apache HttpComponents HttpClient

Answer (score 4):

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/2")

request.addHeader("Referer", "http://www.example.com/1")

HttpResponse response = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request)
```

You can set *header* by using `AbstractHttpMessage` `addHeader`

Comment: I believe the header as transmitted on the wire is called `Referer`, not `HTTP_REFERER`.

Comment: @GregKopff Yeah, Thanks.